# I get error when I load my login page becuase of my sql query function

Tags: php

I am getting this error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs

My code:

```
function dbQuery($sql)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_connect_error());

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: The error says it all, look at the manual. Also `mysqli_connect_error` is for connection errors. Use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php.

Answer (score 0):

It's inside a function, MySQLi is not having access to your connection as far as I know.

If your database connection is named $conn, you can write it like:

```
function dbQuery($sql) {
    global $conn;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_connect_error());

    return $result; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the manual on how to use mysqli_query: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php. The correct way to use it is:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

where $conn is your mysqli connection, and $sql is the query to run.